# Automating New User Creation With C# Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, active-directory

I created a web service which can be called from a form to add new users to the system. The final service will add users to Active Directory and Exchange in the required format (please note that `FirstName` and `LastName` are required fields in the form, so they will never be `null`):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace NewStarterWebService
{
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class NewStarter : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public void CreateNewUser(
            string firstName, 
            string middleName, 
            string lastName, 
            string jobTitle, 
            string department, 
            string office, 
            string role,
            string manager)
        {
            var newUser = new NewUser(firstName, middleName, lastName, jobTitle, department, office, role, manager);
            newUser.Create();
        }
    }
}
```

The `NewUser` Class only has 1 method - `Create()` and a constructor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NewStarterWebService
{
    public class NewUser
    {
        public readonly string FullName;
        public readonly string FirstName;
        public readonly string MiddleName;
        public readonly string LastName;
        public readonly string Department;
        public readonly string Office;
        public readonly string JobTitle;
        public readonly string Role;
        public readonly string Manager;
        public readonly string Email; 
        public readonly string DotName;
        public readonly string HomeDirectory;
        public readonly string Initials;

        public readonly Dictionary<string, string> DefaultProperties;
        private const string Password = "Password99";

        public NewUser(
            string firstName,
            string middleName,
            string lastName,
            string jobTitle,
            string department,
            string office,
            string role,
            string manager)
        {
            Office = office;
            Department = department;
            FirstName = firstName.Trim();
            MiddleName = middleName.Trim();
            LastName = lastName.Trim();
            JobTitle = jobTitle.Trim();
            Role = role.Trim();

            Manager = Ad.GetManagerDistinguishedName(manager);
            FullName = $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
            Email = $"{FirstName}{LastName}@domain.com";
            DotName = $"{FirstName}.{LastName}";
            HomeDirectory = $@"\\File\Home$\{DotName}";
            try
            {
                Initials = $"{FirstName[0]}{MiddleName[0]}{LastName[0]}";
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (
                ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException || 
                ex is NullReferenceException || 
                ex is ArgumentNullException)
            {
                Initials = $"{FirstName[0]}{LastName[0]}";
            }

            // Set the default properties for AD
            DefaultProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"userprincipalname",           Email},
                {"samaccountname",              DotName },
                {"sn",                          LastName},
                {"givenname",                   FirstName },
                {"displayname",                 FullName },
                {"description",                 JobTitle },
                {"mail",                        Email },
                {"homedirectory",               HomeDirectory },
                {"homedrive",                   "H:" },
                {"physicalDeliveryOfficeName",  Office },
                {"Manager",                     Manager },
                {"Initials",                    Initials }
            };
        }

        public void Create()
        {
            Ad.CreateUser(this);
            Ps.AddExchangeUser(this);
        }     
    }
}
```

In the constructor, `Manager` is initialised with a call to the `AD` class, because the manager's `DisplayName` is sent through, but for my purposes I need this to be the `DsitinguishedName`.

The `Create()` method makes a call to `Ad` (Active Directory) and `Ps` (PowerShell) to do the AD and Exchange creation. I didn't post this code because I thought that it would maybe be a bit much but if people think it would help to put the rest of it in context I will add it!

Comment: You say that `FirstName` and `LastName` never may be null, but could they be empty ?

Comment: @Heslacher You are so right ... Just tried submitting the form where `FirstName` and `LastName` are made up of some spaces and the form tried to submit - I will have to handle that in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not put dependency on singleton in this class – it means two responsibility for `NewUser` - format properties and orchestrate AD API. Let’s define this helper class to be more explicit on your validation scenarios:

```
static class Trimming
{
    public static string TrimRequired(this string value, [CallerMemberName] string property = "")
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Mailformed property {property}.");

        return value.Trim();
    }

    public static string TrimOptional(this string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return value.Trim();
    }
}
```

And define `UserBuilder` (It makes sense to prefer properties over ctor parameters when we have so many):

```
public class UserBuilder
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, string> ToProperties() =>
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"userprincipalname", RequiredEmail},
            {"samaccountname", RequiredDotName },
            {"sn", RequiredLastName},
            {"givenname", RequiredFirstName },
            {"displayname", RequiredFullName },
            {"description", OptionalJobTitle },
            {"mail", RequiredEmail },
            {"homedirectory", RequiredHomeDirectory },
            {"homedrive", "H:" },
            {"physicalDeliveryOfficeName", OptionalOffice },
            {"Manager", RequiredManager },
            {"Initials", RequiredInitials }
        };

    string RequiredFullName => $"{RequiredFirstName} {RequiredLastName}";
    string RequiredEmail => $"{RequiredFirstName}{RequiredLastName}@domain.com";
    string RequiredDotName => $"{RequiredFirstName}.{RequiredLastName}";
    string RequiredHomeDirectory => $@"\\File\Home$\{RequiredDotName}";

    string RequiredInitials
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return $"{RequiredFirstName[0]}{OptionalMiddleName[0]}{RequiredLastName[0]}";
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (
                ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException ||
                ex is NullReferenceException ||
                ex is ArgumentNullException)
            {
                return $"{RequiredFirstName[0]}{RequiredLastName[0]}";
            }
        }
    }

    string OptionalOffice => Office.TrimOptional();
    string OptionalDepartment => Department.TrimOptional();
    string RequiredFirstName => FirstName.TrimRequired();
    string OptionalMiddleName => MiddleName.TrimOptional();
    string RequiredLastName => LastName.TrimRequired();
    string OptionalJobTitle => JobTitle.TrimOptional();
    string RequiredRole => Role.TrimRequired();
    string RequiredManager => Manager.TrimRequired();
}
```

P.S. Generally speaking, it makes sense to do not hold an intermediate state of you calculations (like trimmed string values) – just an original data + define functions/properties to process them. It makes your design more flexible.

P.P.S. It might be useful to have `UserName` class:

```
   class UserName
   {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string FullName => ...
        public string Initials => ...
   }
```

... and use in `UserBuilder`.

Answer (score 3):

My biggest concerns are that I miss some data validation. Sure you say that `FirstName` and `LastName` won't be null, but they may be either `Empty` or have only whitespace.

But what about the passed in `middleName` ? If `middleName` is `null` then a call to `MiddleName = middleName.Trim();` would blow in your face wich is the same for `jobTitle` and `role`.

---

Using the classname `NewUser` will make me wonder what you will do if you need a user to be updated or deleted. Will you then add another class `EditedUser` and `DeletableUser`?

Why don't you name it `ADUser` or `ActiveDirectoryUser` instead ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that `JobTitle` and `Role` are both submitted via dropdown boxes, so I felt safe about these. With everything else you are totally right - maybe I will just rename the class `User` as they will be added to various systems eventually

Answer (score 2):

This annoys me:

```
public readonly string FullName;
```

And that's because `readonly` is [a modifier for fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx). Instead, I'd expect this:

```
public string FullName {get; private set; }
```

Comment: I was thinking exactly this but had no idea why I should change it - didn't feel right to make a change if I didn't have a real reason. I still can't really tell why properties are better when a `readonly` field also disallows public `setting`. I guess making it a property lets methods other than the constructor make changes to it

Comment: If OP is using C# 6, it could be as simple as `public string FullName { get; }` and it would behave just like his readonly field. Using `private set` opens the field up to be modified within the class, not exactly the same semantics as OP's code.

Comment: @RubberDuck Does this mean that excluding `private set;` allows for modification in the constructor and no-where else (similar to `readonly`) in C#6 ?

Comment: @Bassie https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/whats-new-in-c-6/